# DOM javascript Form elements accessing

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, getelementbyid

I have started javascript DOM manipulation, I come across an error maybe.
Whenever I input in name field like **jaykumar** and press **click me** button .In **demo**, **jaykumar** comes and with in few microseconds go.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements["fname"].value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  name<input type="textbox" name="fname"> email
  <input type="textbox" name="email">
  <button onclick="myfunction()"> Click me</button>

</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: That’s because `button` creates a _submit button_ by default, so the form submits, and that makes your page reload. Use `type="button"` to make it a click button instead.

Comment: it worked. But giving "[object HTMLInputElement]" instead of name "jaykumar"

Comment: @Jaykumar note in my edit of your question I added `.value` (I thought this was a typo but fixes the problem you stated). Also see my answer.

Comment: hi , if I want to access name and email with only 
  var x =document.getElementById("myform").elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button inside a form's default behaviour is to submit the form. To change this make the button of `type="button"`

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myform").elements["fname"].value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  name<input type="textbox" name="fname"> email
  <input type="textbox" name="email">
  <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()"> Click me</button>

</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```